# How to paste copied text without formatting

Tags: email, copy-paste, text, text-editor, shortcut-menu

Text copied do clipboard with `Command+C` shortcut and paste with `Command+V` contains formatting.

Some editors have a dedicated function that allows removing formatting.
But when I'm composing an email with *the Apple Mail* app, copying and pasting an element from websites, previous emails, etc. original formatting makes it look horrible.

Is there **a simple way** to paste copied text with removed formatting?

Answer (score 5):

**Paste & Match Style** -  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>

This is almost a global command across Apple apps.

[image]

Comment: You could also run the text through something like TextBuddy to strip the formatting.

Comment: @MarcWilson - Well, you could paste it via a textedit document in plaintext too.. but why the extra step?